# Why does the iterator to set::end in C++ dereferences to the number of elements in the set?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

In C++-STL, set::end() returns an iterator pointing to past-the-last element of the set container. Since it does not refer to a valid element, it cannot de-referenced end() function returns a bidirectional iterator.

But when I execute the following code:

```
set<int> s;

s.insert(1);
s.insert(4);
s.insert(2);

// iterator pointing to the end
auto pos2 = s.end();
cout<<*pos2;
```

it prints `3` as output. The output increases as I insert more elements to the set and is always equal to the total number of elements in the set.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The "end" iterator is not pointing to an element in the container, you must never dereference it. Doing so leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 8):

Dereferencing the `end()` iterator is undefined behavior, so anything is allowed to happen. Ideally you'd get a crash, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case here and everything "seems" to work.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is *undefined behaviour*, in this particular case the observed behaviour could be due to implementation details of the standard library in use.

[`std::set::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/size) has O(1) complexity, but `std::set` is a node-based container (internally a binary search tree). So the size needs to be stored somewhere withing the data structure. It could be that the `end()` iterator points at a location that doubles as storage for the size, and by pure chance, you're able to access it.

Answer (score 2):

> Since it does not refer to a valid element, it cannot de-referenced

It can, as your test code demonstrated. However, it *shouldn't* be dereferenced.